# Apache2 serving two angular2 apps

Tags: apache, angular

How can I serve two angular2 apps on the same apache2 server. Ex:

localhost <- serves the main app (frontpage)

localhost/xyz <- serves the secondary app

BR

Comment: just put the second app in folder `xyz` of the root thas it nothing special. For example if the root folder is `/var/www/html` and first app files are there just put second app files in `/var/www/html/xyz`, ofcourse you should have your `index.html` or `index.php` files

Comment: Hi does not seem to work... it loads the corret index.html but somehow the old javascript with the old angular2 app is still in the browser...

Comment: Try remove browser history from last hour, javascript is probably cached. Removing history from one hour is forcing browser to download scripts again